# PHP - Regex for more than one capital letter?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to write a PHP script that finds all words in a list or a paragraph that have more than one capital letter - or a mix of at least 1 letter and 1 number.  I Can find one capital letter, but 2 capital letters in a word is an issue.

Thank you

Comment: please show an example of how you attempted to do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: not sure why the question was voted down twice... it's not a duplicate I think since I did a search before.

Comment: Probably because it's unclear. By the way, don't forget to accept the right answer clicking the green V symbol. ;)

Comment: Read the `title` on the downvote button: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your question right. These regular expressions matches all the words that have at least 2 capital letters in them or have at least 1 letter + 1 number (e.g. *HEllo, HellO, Hello1, hello2*, etc). It uses the space as separator so it might fail with punctuation, including commas, points and other things in the matches.

```
$text = 'Text';
preg_match_all('#(?<= )([^ ]*\p{Lu}[^ ]*\p{Lu}[^ ]*(?= )|[^ ]*\p{L}[^ ]*\p{N}[^ ]*|[^ ]*\p{N}[^ ]*\p{L}[^ ]*)(?= )#u', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

(Explanation: it matches every word that is preceded and followed by a space (but don't include them in the match), which has something that's not a space repeated 0, 1 or more times, a capital letter, again a non-space repeated 0, 1 or more times, again a capital letter and again something that's a non-space, or the same but in place of the capital letters you have a letter and a number, or a number and a letter)

In order to use this you need `PHP > 5.1.0`. The advantage is that it matches all the unicode characters that are considered letters or numbers, not just ASCII. If you don't need this, or have a minor version of PHP, you can use the ASCII version:

```
$text = 'Text';
preg_match_all('#(?<= )([^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*(?= )|[^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*|[^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*[A-Za-z][^ ]*)(?= )#', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

untested, but in the general right direction:

```
[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*\s
```

In other words, it could start with one or more lower case letters, has a capital letter, maybe another one or more lower case letters, then has another capital letter, and may have lower case letters before a space is found.  You may have to add punctuation etc depending on your use case.